# Application to record sound effects for games

Tags: windows, sound, audio, effects, sound-effects

I'm having kids record sounds using their PCs (a few have Macs as well) for use in the games they create.  The built-in windows 7 sound recorder is surprisingly poor, didn't older versions of windows include a sound recorder that could at least play back the sound you recorded or tell you how long it was?

I tried Audacity, but that is pretty confusing for kids.  They record a sound, don't like it, then want to record again and it merges those 2 sounds instead...  It's also a little confusing trying to simply specify when the sound starts and ends.

Is there some tool game developers use to easily create sound effects from a mic?

Comment: Its not PC/Mac, but I've had good results with my phone, specifically "Tape Machine" for Android.

Comment: I second the advice from @P.T. because all audio apps on a desktop are going to be complex because audio creation and mixing itself is complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Wavesurfer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wavesurfer/) is less daunting and up for the task as described, cross-platform.

Re-recording overwrites the buffer and basic editing is supported.

You must right click on the sound document to create a waveform pane in order to be able to visually select sections of the recorded audio for editing.  Otherwise new documents show just a tape transport and mini-waveform overview.

Comment: Wavesurfer is a little buggy on my Mac (loop play gives popup error dialogs on every loop, doesn't always record properly the first time, etc). But Wavesurfer does seem to do the job pretty easily.